# nixos: How do I install debug symbols into my .nix-profile from a custom package?

Tags: nixos

While I have managed to build debug symbols, they don't appear in .nix-profile/lib/debug when installing via nix-env -iA nixos.kube(.debug)
I can manually point gdb to the relevant debug symbol paths, but those paths change with every update so it's rather inconvenient.

Example debug symbol paths that I have are:
/nix/store/vnrpfx28cgq3ajgmk3a83js5ykr22c3z-kube-develop-debug/lib/debug/
/nix/store/qp6x1aba28430qks5jsfllxsmpgyv30l-sink-develop-debug/lib/debug/

Answer (score 0):

For system-wide packages they will be installed by enabling `environment.enableDebugInfo = true` in configuration.nix

This is implemented in this [module](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/nixos/modules/config/debug-info.nix)

In home manager this can be achieved by using `home.extraOutputsToInstall = ["debug"];`

For home manager `NIX_DEBUG_INFO_DIRS` should then also include `~/.nix-profile/lib/debug`.